# Is tensorflow.data an example of incremental data loading?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I want to clarify more about the functionality of *tf.data*.
Is this library an example of incremental/progressive loading (look [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/large-data-files-machine-learning/) *5. Stream Data or Use Progressive Loading* section)?
The reason why this is done is because the whole dataset does not need to be in memory but only a batch of the dataset

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That link is kinda old (2017) but you can load only the data you need in each batch iteratively, parallelizing IO operations for batches "n-1" WHILE gpu runs on batches "n".

here's a general approach to how it works and which things you can use to optimize the dataset: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance